# How is this for loop executing its iterator out of order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a `for` loop within an `async` function with an `await` involved in the loop. From what I read, for loops are supposed to play nice with `await`, but it seems like there's some unusual behavior that I don't understand.

Consider the func described, abridged down to the fundamentals of the scenario:

```
let counter = 0;
module.exports = async () => {
  console.log("processing iteration", counter); // just here as 
    // a sanity check to make sure multiple funcs aren't running 
    // concurrently to produce the out-of-order for loop iteration
  counter++;
  let keys = [... some array here ...]
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    console.log("processing iteration: [", counter, "] index: [", i, "]")
    if (keys[key] === false) {
      break;
    } else {
      if (Array.isArray(keys[key])) {
        let x = await doStuff(parseInt(key));
        // as suggested in an answer, I tried assigning the result 
        // to a variable to create a closure, but nothing changes 
        // in the output
        doOtherStuff(parseInt(key));
        delete keys[key];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I leave out `await` ahead of `doStuff`, as expected, that stuff gets done out of the desired sequential order, but the array itself loops properly, with every index doing as expected. The logs look like this:

```
processing iteration 125
processing iteration: [ 126 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration: [ 126 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 126 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration: [ 126 ] index: [ 3 ]
processing iteration: [ 126 ] index: [ 4 ]
```

But if I do use `await`, which needs to be used to get these asynchronous tasks (the `doStuff` tasks involve database reads so I cannot make them synchronous) done in sequential order, craziness occurs.

Specifically, once `await` is used, at first when the function is called, it works pretty much as expected:

```
processing iteration 15
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 3 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 4 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 5 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 6 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 7 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 8 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 9 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 10 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 11 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 12 ]
processing iteration: [ 16 ] index: [ 13 ]
```

But this function gets called many times as the simulation progresses and whereas those logs show it running fine by the 16th iteration, as soon as something changes with what's going on inside `doStuff` (and it would be harder to explain what exactly is changing inside, but other processing and looping starts occurring inside once certain conditions are met) the iterators start being executed multiple times:

```
processing iteration 147
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 1 ]
... something changes here with what's happening inside of doStuff ..
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 148 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration 148
processing iteration: [ 149 ] index: [ 0 ]
```

and then not only the indexes repeat, but in the following func iteration count, the `for` loops starts iterating out of loop order:

```
processing iteration 148
processing iteration: [ 149 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration 149
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 1 ]
processing iteration: [ 150 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration 150
processing iteration: [ 151 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration 151
processing iteration: [ 152 ] index: [ 0 ]
processing iteration: [ 152 ] index: [ 2 ]
processing iteration 152
processing iteration: [ 153 ] index: [ 0 ]
```

Is there something that I'm fundamentally failing to understand about `for loops` and `async` and `await` that can be explained just looking at this abridged version of the code? There must be something I'm missing because it seems to me that while using await it should be absolutely impossible for those `for` loop iterators to print out of order.

If need be, I'll post a full version of the code, including what happens within `doStuff`, I just abridged it to keep the question as succinct as possible unless more detail is necessary.

Comment: If there's not some fundamental, immediately obvious explanation for the behavior here, just let me know and Ill post the un-abridged code, including what happens within `doStuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the 9000 logs, and the breakdown of the indexing when that happens.  The outer function is async, so they are put in the event loop, and will get mixed in with the await calls in the event loop.
And so the next iteration after the awaits end up using the value of counter after it has already been incremented.
Notice also that the output happens altogether after 1 second passes.

The key take away is that the await is like a "[yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)", which causes it to exit the function and yield a Promise, and places it in the event loop.

So what can happen, is that when an await is hit, the execution gets deferred, so that counter is changed while it is waiting in the event loop at the awaited position.

```js
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
counter2++
module.exports()
}
counter2 = 9000
```

```html
<script>
var module = {},doStuff=()=>new Promise(r=>Math.random()<0.5?setTimeout(r,1000):r()),doOtherStuff=()=>{}
var counter2 = 0
let counter = 0;
module.exports = async () => {
  console.log("processing iteration", counter); // just here as 
    // a sanity check to make sure multiple funcs aren't running 
    // concurrently to produce the out-of-order for loop iteration
  counter++;
        console.log(counter2)
  let keys = [1,2,6,6,1,6,[1],[1],10]
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    console.log("processing iteration: [", counter, "] index: [", i, "]")
    if (keys[key] === false) {
      break;
    } else {
      if (Array.isArray(keys[key])) {
        let x = await doStuff(parseInt(key));
        console.log(counter2)
        // as suggested in an answer, I tried assigning the result 
        // to a variable to create a closure, but nothing changes 
        // in the output
        doOtherStuff(parseInt(key));
        delete keys[key];
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

await all calls to module.exports() so execution order is in the order you expect (each call to module.exports() finishes before the next one continues)

```js
// every call to module.exports() is awaited on,
// so it won't continue until the last one is finished
// and execution flow will behave as you are expecting
(async()=>{
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
counter2++
await module.exports()
}
})()
counter2 = 9000
// notice how counter2 is 1 at the beginning of the first call to module.exports()
// and then 9000 after the await in module.exports()
```

```html
<script>
var module = {},doStuff=()=>new Promise(r=>Math.random()<0.5?setTimeout(r,1000):r()),doOtherStuff=()=>{}
var counter2 = 0
let counter = 0;
module.exports = async () => {
  console.log("processing iteration", counter); // just here as 
    // a sanity check to make sure multiple funcs aren't running 
    // concurrently to produce the out-of-order for loop iteration
  counter++;
        console.log(counter2)
  let keys = [1,2,6,6,1,6,[1],[1],10]
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    console.log("processing iteration: [", counter, "] index: [", i, "]")
    if (keys[key] === false) {
      break;
    } else {
      if (Array.isArray(keys[key])) {
        let x = await doStuff(parseInt(key));
        console.log(counter2)
        // as suggested in an answer, I tried assigning the result 
        // to a variable to create a closure, but nothing changes 
        // in the output
        doOtherStuff(parseInt(key));
        delete keys[key];
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: wow that is really trippy. Would this be fixed by converting the for loop to a recursive function call that waits on each promise to complete before continuing?

Comment: This actually constitutes "working as intended", since async/await is supposed to defer execution, and "fixed" would have to depend on what you are trying to do.  You should not be depending on global variable `counter`  to track execution flow order, when your exported function is asynchronous and your calling code isn't waiting on it.  Basically, the only thing you should "depend" on as "Promised" for the variable `counter`, is that it will reach `10`  (or whatever result it is supposed to end up with) if you await all the calls that act on variable `counter`.  The global is the problem

Comment: See the second example, where execution doesn't get deferred in between, because each call to module.exports() is awaited on before continuing on to the next call.  The gist of it is async all the way to the "top".  If I have multiple calls to Promise wrapped or async functions, if I don't explicitly await them, I should expect that they may get deferred and the order that their Promises resolve may be different.

Comment: Notice how the second example resolves in batches of 1 second, instead of like the first one that instantly finishes and then executes all of them after 1 second after the awaits later with a value of 9000.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. This solved my problem